# New Mapped SparseMatrix type RcppEigen compilation errors

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

Since RcppEigen version 3.3.3.0 the `MappedSpareMatrixT` has been [deprecated](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/NEWS.Rd#L18). For some reason when compiling functions with this new type  I get errors.

For example (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160815/mappedsparsematrix-in-rcppeigen));

**EDIT:** with suggestions from coatless - still getting same errors.

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>

typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> > mappedSparseMatrix;
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> mappedVector;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::VectorXd cgSparse(const mappedSparseMatrix A, const mappedVector b) {
  Eigen::ConjugateGradient< mappedSparseMatrix, Eigen::Lower > cg(A);
  return cg.solve(b);
}
```

I have tried different things, even copied the type from the Rcppeigen [unitTests](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/unitTests/runit.sparse.R#L147);

```
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::ColMajor> > MapMat;
```

In both cases I get the following errors;

[image: errors]

SessionInfo() here:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppEigen_0.3.3.3.0  RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   Matrix_1.2-9     RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0      Rcpp_0.12.10     grid_3.4.0      
[7] lattice_0.20-35
```

With the mentioned changes - how can I map my sparse matrices? For example, in the above function `sparseCG`? (NB: I am C++ newbie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a note in the files `RcppEigenForward.h` and `RcppEigenWrap.h` that the `mappedSparseMatrix` was deprecated upstream starting with Eigen 3.3.0.

If I change it to

```
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix< double > mappedSparseMatrix;
```

ie use an outright sparse matrix (as opposed to a map to it) then it compiles.

Comment: `MappedSparseMatrix<T>` -> `Map<SparseMatrix>` class

Comment: Yes, that is true. However I was under the impression that mapping was more memory efficient (i.e. [it maps rather than copies](https://github.com/RcppCore/rcpp-gallery/blob/gh-pages/src/2013-01-11-eigen-eigenvalues.cpp#L22)). My datasets can get very large - therefore I thought it best to avoid creating a copy each time. On top of that, not sure it means that is deprecated upstream? So it will slowly be phased out in future?

Comment: All questions for upstream.  Was not our decision.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question then (?) - how with the upstream changes can I still 'map' my sparse matrices?

Comment: Using the `Map<SparseMatrix<Type>>` syntax as I initially mentioned above. See definitions in the [`RcppEigenForward.h`](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/c03cd8a7c657a15872025a93dcc7e9e7b314dd76/inst/include/RcppEigenForward.h#L53-L56) file.

Comment: @coatless, I am under the impression I already did as you said. Like mentioned in the post - i directly copied the definitions from the unit tests.

Comment: I just played with your example. It looks like the routine [`ConjugateGradient`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ConjugateGradient.html) does not _support_ MappedSparseMatrices. So, trying to put a mapped sparse in blows it up. The exporters are fine (@eddelbuettel: unit test should be moved away from `cxxfunction`...) This should be filed as a bug with the Eigen project.

Comment: @coatless, Thanks a lot for the effort and explanation!